# Opening .obj file in VS 3D Renderer

Tags: visual-studio

How can I open .obj file in 3D Renderer in Visual Studio 2017? Because when I trying to open particular .obj file I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbTzO.jpg)

Comment: Have you read the doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/jj170489(v%3dvs.120)

Comment: Not yet, but thanks. =) I am going to read it.